# Ndef data written in mifare 1k card not getting detected

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, ndef

I have written Ndef data in a Mifare card, I want it to be readable by any android device having NFC support, irrespective of whether if supports Mifare cards.

Some of the phones like Honor 8 pro(Does not have Mifare support) can read the tag but others like Samsung J7 are not able to read it.

I have attached card data in an image.[image: Mifare Data Dump]
I have made the sector 2 and onwards private by using a non-standerd key

```
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
// This is getting called for all devices
 Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
}
```

ndef is null in Samsung j7, whereas it has an object in Honor 8 pro.

Any idea why this might be happening or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Where do you have the info from, that the Honor 8 pro doesn't support Mifare, while the Samsung J7 does?

Comment: I meant to say both Honor 8 pro and Samsung j7 does not have Mifare support, but Honor is able to read Ndef data in Mifare cards whereas J7 isn't. [Mifare supported device list](https://www.shopnfc.com/en/content/7-nfc-compatibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that on some mobile phones the OS doesn't report Mifare support, although Mifare Classic cards can be read just fine. Android is supposed to report the `com.nxp.mifare` system feature, if Mifare support is present, but some phones don't.

Some apps like [NFC Check by Tapkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tpky.tools.nfccheck) therefore sometimes report Mifare support as absent, although it's present. To be clear, this is not these apps' fault but rather the fault of the OS. Some older Moto phones are known to have this issue. According to your description it seems, that the Honor 8 pro has the same issue too, otherwise it wouldn't return an `Ndef` instance. On the other hand, probably the Samsung J7 actually really doesn't support Mifare, which is why it doesn't return a `Ndef` instance.

From your question I infer, that you are talking about *Mifare Classic* cards. Note, that in contrast to Mifare Classic, other Mifare cards, i.e. Mifare DESFire cards, can act as Type 4 NDEF tags and can therefore even be read by phones that don't have support for the proprietary Mifare classic. This is because Type 4 NDEF tags are standardized. They are based on the standardized ISO 7816 protocol and are supported by close to all NFC-enabled phones.

So making a long story short, probably you won't be able to read Mifare classic cards with phones that *really* don't have Mifare support while reading cards like the Mifare DESFire should work just fine. Other pros of the DESFire are, that they are more secure, bigger in size and more flexible. The biggest downside is, that they are significantly more expensive.

Comment: Yes, I  am using Mifare classic, but as far as I know, Mifare classic cards can also act like NDEF tags. Data and keys have to be in specified formats as per the document https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1305.pdf

Comment: Another reference: https://www.mifare.net/support/forum/topic/is-mifare-se-cards-support-ndef-format-encoding-and-all-types-of-ndef-messages/

Comment: Just double checked. I can confirm, that the Honor 8 pro doesn't report the `com.nxp.mifare` feature. I can *not* confirm, whether or not it can read Mifare Classic tags.

It's correct, that Mifare tags can act as NDEF tags, but if a phone is not able to read Mifare Classic, it's also not able to read the NDEF stored on the card. As I explained, some phones have Mifare support but the phone doesn't report it. The Honor 8 Pro seems to be such a case. This is why it can read Mifare tags but this doesn't change the fact, that other phones can't.

Comment: I can confirm, Honor 8 pro can definitely read Ndef data written in Mifare classic

Comment: So then obviously, it's a case where Mifare support seems to be present, although not indicated by the OS, so what the OS reports is incorrect. On the other hand, the Samsung J7 probably is a case, where the OS correctly reports, that Mifare support is missing. That's why it's possible on the Honor 8 Pro to read a Mifare Classic-based NDEF tag, while on the Samsung J7 it isn't. There's no way I know to make a device like the Samsung J7 read such a tag.